# Ionic's $http.post not working properly on iOS 9 device

Tags: ios, angularjs, ajax, cordova, ionic-framework

so this is issue is driving me nuts. I have an application built on Ionic 1.1 (1.7 CLI version) which communicates to a RESTful API through ajax requests. The API uses tokens for security.

The problem is that it works fine on web browser, emulator and (as far as I remember) on previous versions of iOS; but it just doesn't work on my iPhone 6 plus with iOS 9.

It seems to be a known issue, and I have already patched it as [this post](http://blog.ionic.io/ios-9-potential-breaking-change/) recommends on its most recent update; as well I have applied the patch on the Transport Security issue, suggested on [this another post](http://blog.ionic.io/preparing-for-ios-9/).

I am trying to understand why other people are not complaining about these methods not working for them and I am guessing that it is because I am using an interceptor for my $http requests. This is my interceptor:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$location', '$localStorage', function ($q, $location, $localStorage) {
            return {
                'request': function (config) {
                    config.headers = config.headers || {};
                    if ($localStorage.token) {
                        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $localStorage.token;
                    }
                    return config;
                },
                'responseError': function (response) {
                    if (response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
                        $location.path('/signin');
                    }
                    return $q.reject(response);
                }
            };
        }]);
```

It is failing on the login action, so there is no token yet, therefore it is not being sent.

As requested on the comments, these are the contents of the .plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>icon.png</string>
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
          <string>icon-40</string>
          <string>icon-small</string>
          <string>icon-60</string>
          <string>icon.png</string>
          <string>icon@2x</string>
          <string>icon-72</string>
          <string>icon-72@2x</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
        <false/>
      </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
          <string>icon-small</string>
          <string>icon-40</string>
          <string>icon-50</string>
          <string>icon-76</string>
          <string>icon-60</string>
          <string>icon</string>
          <string>icon@2x</string>
          <string>icon-72</string>
          <string>icon-72@2x</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
        <false/>
      </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.ionicframework.antros473056</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>0.0.1</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>0.0.1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile~ipad</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>UILaunchImages</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 480}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 480}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-568h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 568}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-568h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 568}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-667h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{375, 667}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-667h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{375, 667}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-736h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{414, 736}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-Landscape-736h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{414, 736}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{768, 1024}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{768, 1024}</string>
      </dict>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

The XCode console is not giving me feedback about what happens, so I don't know what other details can be useful for you guys so you can better help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show what you `.plist` file looks like?

Comment: Thanks, I've just added that info.